# React is correctly receiving props but become undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-props

I am passing props to a component that correctly receives its value but become undefined.

```
const ImageView = () => {
  const { image } = useMedia();
  
  return image.map(img => (
    <Drag key={img.id} mediaId={img.id} pos={{x: img.x, y: img.y}} >
      <img src={backFiles + img.link} alt="" />
    </Drag>
  ));
};
```

The Drag component is doing that:

```
const Drag = ({children, mediaId, pos}) => {
  console.log(pos)
  ...
  return (
    <Article>
      {children}
    </Article>
  );
};
```

When I console.log pos look what happens:

console.log(pos):

[image: console.log(pos)]

Here is the content of the image.

console.log(image):

[image]

Console logging mediaId reproduces the same error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that image array has 2 correct data and one empty object?

Comment: Can you try `console.log(image)` in the `ImageView` component?

Comment: @Houssam yes, it works perfectly.

Comment: @RafaelCaixeta Can you share what it shows? I am wondering what the content of `image` is.

Comment: @RafaelCaixeta, I see that you're returning `image.map` in `ImageView`, but you should return a component. Can you nest the image.map inside a fragment like `return <>{image.map....}</>`

Comment: @Harkunwar thanks for comment, it is correct. Answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageView component should return a component, it currently returns an array instead.

Change ImageView to the following:

```js
const ImageView = () => {
  const { image } = useMedia();

  return (
    <>
      {image.map((img) => (
        <Drag key={img.id} mediaId={img.id} pos={{ x: img.x, y: img.y }}>
          <img src={backFiles + img.link} alt="" />
        </Drag>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

image.map needs to return something. The Error could be occurring from there

```
    const ImageView = () => {
  const { image } = useMedia();
  
  return image.map(img => (
  return ( <Drag key={img.id} mediaId={img.id} pos={{x: img.x, y: img.y}} >
              <img src={backFiles + img.link} alt="" />
           </Drag>)
          ));
         };
```

Comment: I don't think that's the error, the OP is just using the correct ES6 syntax for return.